# Fix enumerate/itemize environment spacing

Tags: spacing, enumerate, itemize, theorems

I am using a template (https://github.com/glederrey/EPFL_thesis_template/tree/master/head) for a document.
It has a series of issues when introducing a variety of environments (Theorem, Lemma, Proof, Enumerate, Itemize).

I managed to fix the issue around theorems with this code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=1pt
  \thm@postskip=0pt
}
```

But the problem just keeps presenting itself in other forms.
Like with this enumerate:
[image]

Or with this proposition (also appears for Lemma):
[image]

Where the Proposition environment is defined as follows:

```
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
```

Otherwise, if I have a Theorem, followed by some text and then a Proof:
[image]

Could you help me fix the issue for all of them? Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add before `\begin{document}`

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep} %% Remove the vertical space altogether in all lists
```

Before

[image: A]

After

[image: B]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also have a similar issue with the Theorem and Proof environment. Do you know how to fix that too?

Comment: @user1868607 Could you please add to your question an example of your definitions and a minimal proof and theorem showing the problem? There is none in your link.

Comment: I added it, thanks!